# Non-exhaustive patterns error con matrices en Haskell

Tags: haskell

¿qué tal? 
Estoy haciendo unos ejercicios con Haskell y a la hora de compilar el programa me da un error como si me faltara un patrón en "cab". Realmente no sé cuál puede ser.
Estuve toda la tarde buscando el error pero no lo puedo encontrar.
El ejercicio básicamente de vuelta una matriz "[[2,8,14],[3,9,15],[4,10,16]]"
a "[[2,3,4],[8,9,10],[14,15,16]]"

Adjunto el código

```
cab :: [Int] -> Int
cab (x:y) = x

todasLasCabezas :: [[Int]] -> [Int]
todasLasCabezas [] = []
todasLasCabezas (x:y) = cab(x) : todasLasCabezas(y)


todasLasColas :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
todasLasColas [] = []
todasLasColas ((u:v):z) = v : todasLasColas(z)


darVueltaLista :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
darVueltaLista [] = []
darVueltaLista (x:y) = todasLasCabezas(x:y) : darVueltaLista(todasLasColas(x:y))

main = do
print (darVueltaLista([[2,8,14],[3,9,15],[4,10,16]]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Estuve revisando tu código y vi que tienes algunos errores y no precisamente con tu función `cab`, primeramente necesitas una condición de parada para tu recursividad en el método **todasLasCabezas**, lo resolví de esta forma:

```
todasLasCabezas (x:y) = if length y == 0 then [cab(x)] else cab(x) : todasLasCabezas(y)
```

Si te das cuenta cuando llegamos al final de la lista `y` que es la cola estará vacío, por lo que compara si su longitud es 0, en ese caso solo hago `[cab(x)]`(los corchetes es para convertirlo a tipo [Int] que es lo que retorna el método), en caso contrario obtengo la cabecera y añado la siguiente: `cab(x) : todasLasCabezas(y)`.

Para **todasLasColas** es necesario hacer lo mismo, verificar que `z` no esté vacío, cuando está vacío terminamos la recursividad haciendo `[v]`:

```
todasLasColas ((u:v):z) = if length z /= 0 then v : todasLasColas(z) else [v]
```

Y la parte más importante está en tu función "principal" **darVueltaLista**, si te das cuenta en tu código la función se manda a llamar una y otra vez sin ninguna esperanza de que se detenga, aquí lo que hice fue comparar que `x`(cabecera de la lista) tenga un tamaño mayor a 1, en ese caso puedes llamar a ambas funciones y repetir el proceso. Sólo cuando su tamaño es menor únicamente llamamos a **todasLasCabezas**.

**Código**

```
cab :: [Int] -> Int
cab (x:y) = x

todasLasCabezas :: [[Int]] -> [Int]
todasLasCabezas (x:y) = if length y == 0 then [cab(x)] else cab(x) : todasLasCabezas(y)


todasLasColas :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
todasLasColas ((u:v):z) = if length z /= 0 then v : todasLasColas(z) else [v]


darVueltaLista :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
darVueltaLista (x:y) = if length x > 1 then todasLasCabezas(x:y) : darVueltaLista(todasLasColas(x:y)) else [todasLasCabezas(x:y)]


main = do
    print (darVueltaLista [[2,8,14],[3,9,15],[4,10,16]])
```

Te recomiendo leer este [Libro de haskell](http://aprendehaskell.es/) tiene temas muy buenos, no se mucho de Haskell pero espero haberte ayudado, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Excepto la función cab, todo tu código es correcto.

```
cab (x:y)= x
```

Necesita que la lista no este vacía. x toma el valor del primer elemento, y toma el valor de la lista sin el primer elemento. En este caso, te falta tener en cuenta la lista vacía.
El código correcto es:

```
cab :: [a] -> a
cab [] = error "Una lista vacia no tiene cabecera"
cab (x:ys) = x
```

Si la lista esta vacía se genera un error. De otro modo se devuelve el primer elemento. Un par de mejoras es llamar al segundo argumento ys, dando a entender que se trata de una lista. Además, si usas a como tipo de dato, este es un generico que te sirve para cualquier tipo de dato.

Por ultimo, a menos que el ejercicio solicite que desarrolles la función, te recomiendo usar la función head, que hace exactamente lo mismo.

Saludos!